# Set/get value for field in social pane when adding phone call activity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to automatically change the value for "call with" when opening the form for adding a phone call activity with social pane in contact form:

[image]

I want to set value of the account the contact is assigned to instead, is this possible? I've tried with `Xrm.Page.getAttribute('to')` but it returns `null`.

When accessing a subgrids you need this code `Xrm.Page.getControl("SUBGRID_NAME");`, something similar for social panes?

Comment: To set value use `Xrm.Page.getAttribute('to').setValue(...)`

Comment: @ASpirin `Xrm.Page.getAttribute('to')` returns null

Comment: Ahh, ok clear. Would be nice if you would update the question.

Comment: The form `Quick Form` is readonly and you cannot add even a field to it. So it is not supported to change that behaviour. You can hijack it using JS. for example `var original = Mscrm.ActivityContainer.activityBarClick;
Mscrm.ActivityContainer.activityBarClick = function(a,b,c){ alert("Hello"); original(a,b,c);}` will do alert on any Add button click, but those fixes can stop working after the next update

Comment: @ASpirin I have tried the unsupported way, I did successfully change the value for "call with" field but when I'm saving the phone call it changes back to the old value.